# Getting bad access while deleting cell and reloading table view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview

I am trying to build a  table using custom UITableViewCell, but after deleting cell and when  I try load the view, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error,here i'm getting data from a dictionary and loading it to table view.

The code for my Table is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell = (uploadCustomCell *)[tabelView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"uploadCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (uploadCustomCell  *)self.uploadCustomcell;
    }
    saveBtnCcell.hidden = YES;
    cell.textNamefield.hidden = YES;
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell.defaultSwitch setEnabled:NO];
    NSMutableArray *dictionary = [contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"dict dict :%@",dictionary);
//
    cell.nameLabelCell.text   = [dictionary valueForKey:@"VideoName"];
    cell.userName.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"User"];
    NSString *defaultVideo = [dictionary valueForKey:@"DefaultVideo"];

    if ([defaultVideo isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [cell.defaultSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [cell.defaultSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

    [cell.defaultSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    cell.thumbImg.image = [arrayimage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    VideoNameTextField.hidden = YES;
    return cell;
}

- (void)setState:(id)sender {
    state = [sender isOn];
   //    NSString *rez = state == YES ? @"YES" : @"NO";
   NSLog(@"state.........:%d",state);
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"height:%f",uploadCustomcell.frame.size.height);
    return 207;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSMutableArray *dictionary = [contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary:%@",dictionary);
    NSLog(@"indexpath:%@",indexPath);
    //
    NSLog(@"at index%d obj:%@",indexPath.row,dictionary);
    NSString *nameDetails = [dictionary valueForKey:@"VideoName"];

    guid = [dictionary valueForKey:@"GUID"];

    detailsNameLbl.text = nameDetails;
    detailsVehImg.image = [arrayimage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:
       (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [contents removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tabelView1 reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: numberOfRows might be the problem ????

Comment: in which line you are getting this error?

Comment: What you have done in this method numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: set an exception breakpoint

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
    {
    NSLog(@"No OF rows:%d",[contents count]);
    return [contents count];
  
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
**[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];**

You must use this method also:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
   return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; 
} 



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
[contents removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
//[tabelView1 reloadData];
```

}