# Table View getting crashed while scrolling

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to build a table using custom UITableViewCell, but while scrolling when the first cell goes to top (i.e hides),app is getting  this error`(EXE_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address = 0x14004122))`   and app is crashing here, I am getting data from a dictionary and loading it to table view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell = (uploadCustomCell *)[tabelView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"uploadCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (uploadCustomCell  *)self.uploadCustomcell;
    }
    saveBtnCcell.hidden = YES;
    cell.textNamefield.hidden = YES;
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell.defaultSwitch setEnabled:NO];
    NSMutableArray *dictionary = [contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"dict dict :%@",dictionary);
    //
    cell.nameLabelCell.text   = [dictionary valueForKey:@"VideoName"];
    cell.userName.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"User"];
    NSString *defaultVideo = [dictionary valueForKey:@"DefaultVideo"];

    if ([defaultVideo isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [cell.defaultSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [cell.defaultSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

    [cell.defaultSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    cell.thumbImg.image = [arrayimage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    VideoNameTextField.hidden = YES;
    return cell;
}

- (void)setState:(id)sender {
    state = [sender isOn];
       //    NSString *rez = state == YES ? @"YES" : @"NO";
      NSLog(@"state.........:%d",state);
  }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"height:%f",uploadCustomcell.frame.size.height);
    return 207;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSMutableArray *dictionary = [contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary:%@",dictionary);
    NSLog(@"indexpath:%@",indexPath);
//
    NSLog(@"at index%d obj:%@",indexPath.row,dictionary);
    NSString *nameDetails = [dictionary valueForKey:@"VideoName"];

    guid = [dictionary valueForKey:@"GUID"];

    detailsNameLbl.text = nameDetails;
    detailsVehImg.image = [arrayimage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:
   (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    {  
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
      [contents removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write error message (Is it array index out of bound Error?)

Comment: this was the error messiage i'm getting EXE_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address = 0x14004122)

Comment: Please format your code and make it actually readable. Plus add the crash log.

Comment: On which line this error is comes?

Comment: put break point on cellForRowAtIndexPath and check at which line it crash.

Comment: it is getting when i scroll the view and when first cell gets hided.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413642/getting-bad-access-while-deleting-cell-and-reloading-table-view

Comment: What is saveBtnCell? The code you posted is incomplete. Complete it with proper code which may help us to debug.

Comment: praveen it is uibutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your code like this  :

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    // Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
    uploadCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    // If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"cell allocated");
        // Use the default cell style.

        cell = [[uploadCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"uploadCustomCell"
                                                     owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    // Add your code here
    return cell;
```

}

Hope it helps you.

Comment: even though it is crashing

Comment: comment all code in cellforRowAtIndexPath and then check is it still crashing.

Comment: Check your uploadCustomCell. Have you made it properly. May be it is crashing due to it.

Comment: ya you are correct i made mistake in upload custom class

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here
Replace this line :

```
cell = (uploadCustomCell *)[tabelView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

by this as following :

```
cell = (uploadCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

Comment: even though it is crashing

Comment: Also it could be a reason that the valueForkey you r trying to access has no value or is missing.